# La propiedad 'value' no existe en el tipo 'HTMLElement'.ts(2339)

Tags: html5, typescript

buenas tardes!

Llevo un buen rato anclado en esta cuestión, pero no encuentro el kit de la cuestión. He probado lo que se comenta en el hilo de Stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989741/the-property-value-does-not-exist-on-value-of-type-htmlelement).

Tengo un formulario en mi HTML con 3 opciones type="radio" con un valor cada una:

```
<form action="" class="score">
    <label for="normal"> <input type="radio" id="normal" value="1" name="score"> 
      Normal <i class="fa-solid fa-face-flushed"></i></label>

    <label for="good"> <input type="radio" id="good" value="2" name="score"> 
      Bueno <i cass="fa-solid fa-face-grin-squint"></i></label>

    <label for="excellent"> <input type="radio" id="excellent" value="3" name="score"> 
      ¡Excelente! <i class="fa-solid fa-face-grin-tears"></i></label>
                <div id="message">MEssage</div>
</form>
```

Y quiero darle ese valor a una constante que tengo en mi archivo '.ts':

```
    const score = document.getElementById('score')!.value;
    console.log(score);
```

Y en Consola me sale este error: "*main.js:45 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')*"

Cuando he comprobado qué valor llega (con 'as HTMLInputElement | null' y un if de comprobación), el valor que daba es **null**.

Un saludo y muchas gracias!

Comment: No tienes ningún elemento con id `"score"`, tienes varios con el **name** `"score"`

Comment: Lo primero es, como menciona Pablo, no tienes ningún elemento con id "score". Lo segundo es, si usas typescript, debes indicarle el tipo del elemento, algo como `const score = (document.getElementById('score') as HTMLInputElement)!.value;`

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuestas. Lo he podido solucionar de esta manera: ```const score = (document.querySelector('input[name="score"]:checked') as HTMLInputElement).value;```. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Veamos, lo primero es que estás usando `getElementById` que como su propio nombre indica **obtiene un elemento HTML por su ID**, y por supuesto, ninguno de los elementos de tu ejemplo tiene como id `"score"`.

Si lo que quieres es leer el input checkado entre los tres que tienes agrupados bajo el nombre `"score"`, aprovechando que usas un `form`, hazlo así:

1º. ponle un ID a tu `<form>` (en mi ejemplo será "miForm")

```
<form action="" class="score" id="miForm">
```

2º: y luego accede al `value` tal como querías:

en Javascript:

```
var puntuacion=document.forms.miForm.score.value;
```

en Typescript:

```
var  formularios = document.forms as any;
var  puntuacion=formularios.miForm.score.value;
```

Comment: En **typeScript** se recomienda usar lo menos posible `any`, por lo que para identificar las propiedades del elemento, se recomienda poner el tipo de elemento, tal como lo recomienda Jaime Mendez en su comentarió: `const score = (document.getElementById('score') as HTMLInputElement)!.value`
En este caso del form, podría ser `HTMLFormElement`